# cannot import name 'balanced_accuracy_score' from scikit learn

Tags: python, importerror

I have an imbalanced data and want to use "balanced_accuracy_score" to evaluate my model. However, it didn't work for me although I updated scikit learn to 0.20 already.

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-266614be2a70> in <module>()
----> 1 from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy_score
      2 

ImportError: cannot import name 'balanced_accuracy_score'
```

Does someone have this issue before and know how to solve this? or is there any alternative ways that I can use for evaluate my imbalanced dataset for binary classification task.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `from sklearn.metrics import balanced_accuracy_score` works on my machine with scikit-learn 0.20.3. If you can import the rest of `sklearn` then that is odd behavior.

However, if you are unable to import anything else from `sklearn` open your shell and make sure that the command `pip list` returns a list of packages which contains the correct version of `sklearn`. It can be a problem with your environment management. Meaning that even though you installed `sklearn 0.20`, your IDE's environment doesn't pick it up.

If `pip list` contains the right package then try running `python` in your shell and importing the package there. If that works, this might mean that your IDE is not picking up the correct installation of python / not picking up your venv.

With respect to you last point in the question [the sklearn documentation for balanced accuracy score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.balanced_accuracy_score.html) states that their definition of this function is equivilent to using [accuracy_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html#sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score) with class-balanced sample weights.

> Some literature promotes alternative definitions of balanced accuracy. Our definition is equivalent to accuracy_score with class-balanced sample weights, and shares desirable properties with the binary case.

You might also want to look at other metrics such as: `roc`, `f-scores` and just plotting a confusion matrix with sample weights.